# Wrong German DateFormat in Java class in Oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle, datetime, date-formatting

I just upgraded a development database to Oracle 12.2 with JDK 1.8.0_121.

If I call the following java code:

```
String strLokal = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance (DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.GERMANY).format(new Date());
```

then `strLokal` is something like `Jun 7, 2017 1:56:34 PM`

If I call the same on my local machine with JDK 1.8.0_20 then I get: `07.06.2017 01:56:34`

Where does the wrong format in the database come from? The desktop format is the correct one, that is also given back by the databases with Oracle 12.1 and JDK 1.6.0_71.

Thanks for every explanation.

Comment: The locale on the server and client don't match?

Comment: they match, but by passing Locale.GERMANY shouldn't it be GERMANY any way?

Comment: Since you are using Java 8 (and even if you didn’t), it’s about time you throw out the outdated classes `Date` and `DateFormat` and use `strLokal = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.GERMANY));`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I have not installed Oracle RDBMS, though. I have tried your code snippet, and also the Java 8 version in my previous comment, on jdk8u101, 8u121 and 8u131, and locales GERMAN and GERMANY. In all cases I get something like `07.06.2017 16:44:08`.

Comment: I changed the code line to your code, without success. It's still returning the non-german format. This happens **only** with the JDK that is running in the Oracle DB (OJVM). "Local" results are fine.

Comment: Yes, it’s an English format (according to the locales in my JVM, the only other language where it is used is Hindi). May sound like a bug somewhere. Just curious, did you try other locales? Does the bug affect all non-Germany locales or only Germany? You may search the net or Oracle documentation of a description of the issue.